# Help solving calculus question?

Tags: calculus

Matt the mechanical engineer bought himself a car. Obviously he wants to take the car out on a test drive. Starting from rest he accelerates in a straight line until the car reaches maximum speed. He observes that the car reaches 30m/s in 3 seconds, and the maximum speed is $100$ m/s. The car's velocity follows the equation $v(t)=A(1-e^{-Bt})$.

a) Solve the values of A and B using the info above

b) Plot the equation with the values for A and B using MATLAB. Comment on whether the plot matches Matt's observations.

c) Determine an expression for the distance the car travels over time. Then solve how long it takes for the car to travel $100$ m by plotting the distance equation.

Please someone help me get answers for this question, as I have an exam and I need to know how this question is answered so I can practice/do other questions similar. I'm not the best at vector calculus.

Comment: Why don't you add a few of your own steps? This will help others understand your level and provide an answer quickly.

Comment: @AksharGandhi I'm pretty bad at this I'm going to admit. All that I was able to do was get to the equation 3=A(1-e^(-3B)).

Answer (score 1):

This question has nothing to do with vector calculus, it is just calculus.

You are given an equation $v(t)=A(1-\exp(-B t))$. You should see from this that the maximum speed is $A$, attained when $t\rightarrow \infty$.

You are given two conditions

- The speed after $3$ seconds is $30$m/s : $v(3)=A(1-\exp(-B 3))=30$
- The maximum speed is $100$ m/s : $A=100$

Two equations, two unknowns. Solve for $A,B$.